# I want to make my toast pop up display something other than the spinner selections and fetch a download link

Tags: android, arrays

So I am pretty new to java and android coding. I have 2 spinners that, when an item is chosen in each and the submit button is pressed, I want the toast to pop up with "Selected (Rate/Rank) Fetching download" and actually be fetching the download.

Here is the spinners xml:

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/rankspin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:entries="@array/rate_array"
    android:prompt="@string/srate" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/ratespin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rankspin"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:entries="@array/rank_array"
    android:prompt="@string/srank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ratespin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/button_label" />
```

Here are the arrays:

```
<string name="srank">Select Rate:</string>
<string name="srate">Select Rank:</string>
<string name="button_label">Submit</string>

<string-array name="rank_array">
    <item>Select Rank:</item>
    <item>E-4</item>
    <item>E-5</item>
    <item>E-6</item>
    <item>E-7</item>
    <item>E-8</item>
    <item>E-9</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="rate_array">
    <item>Select Rate:</item>
    <item>ABE</item>
    <item>ABH</item>
    <item>CTI</item>
    <item>CTM</item>
    <item>CTN</item>
    <item>CTR</item>
    <item>CTT</item>
    <item>YN</item>
</string-array>
```

And finally the java:

```
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.rankspin);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
}

  public void addListenerOnButton() 

  {
          spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.rankspin);
          spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ratespin);
          sbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sbutton);
          sbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 

          {

            public void onClick(View v) 

            {
              Toast.makeText(Bibs.this,
              "Result : " +
              "\nSpinner 1 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
              "\nSpinner 2 : "+ String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          });
  }
```

}

The output im looking for is dependent on both inputs, a combination of rate and rank. For example and input of YN and E4 would result in YN3 as the output.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: aaand is there a problem with your code? what is your question?

Comment: The `Toast` class is just a short term popup to inform the user of something and then disappear - it can't be used to perform actions such as downloading data.

Comment: Well I dont necessarily use the toast itself to download it. Just to combine those 2 things into a message and then use another function to initiate a download based on the information provided.

Comment: kind of like "if input1=this and input2=this then output=this"